# Ignoring Syntax Errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have a file that contains an arbitrary number of lines of c++ code, each line of which is self-contained (meaning it is valid by itself in the main function). However, I do not know how many, if any, of the lines will have valid c++ syntax. An example file might be

```
int length, width; // This one is fine
template <class T className {}; // Throws a syntax error
```

What I want to do is write to a second file all the lines that have valid syntax. Currently, I've written a program in python that reads each line, places it into the following form

```
int main() {
    // Line goes here
    return 0;
}
```

and attempts to compile it, returning True if the compilation succeeds and False if it doesn't, which I then use to determine which lines to write to the output file. For example, the first line would generate a file containing

```
int main() {
    int length, width;
    return 0;
}
```

which would compile fine and return True to the python program. However, I'm curious if there is any sort of try-catch syntax that works with the compiler so I could put each line of the file in a try-catch block and write it to the output if no exception is thrown, or if there's a way I can tell the compiler to ignore syntax errors.

Edit: I've been asked for details about why I would need to do this, and I'll be the first to admit it's a strange question. The reason I'm doing this is because I have another program (of which I don't know all the implementation details) that writes a large number of lines to a file, each of which should be able to stand alone. I also know that this program will almost certainly write lines that have syntax errors. What I'm trying to do is write a program that will remove any invalid lines so that the resulting file can compile without error. What I have in my python program right now works, but I'm trying to figure out if there is a simpler way to do it.

Edit 2: Though I think I've got my answer - that I can't really play try-catch with the compiler, and that's good enough. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I had to reread this a few times. You're asking if there's a flag or some notation you can add to the compiler to ignore the syntax errors and continue compiling anyway?

Comment: What you are (probably) asking for would make **everything** *horribly* broken. Check for the return value of the compiler invocation (it will be *platform-dependent* aka 0 on success, any other value on failure).

Comment: @TankorSmash One solution to the problem I'm dealing with would be to find a way to try-catch with the compiler. Another would be to tell the compiler to just ignore syntax errors, since ultimately I'm going to end up compiling the file that my python program would write out anyway.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli Currently, that's what my python program does - it places the line into the structure above, attempts to compile it, and sends the value of %ERRORLEVEL% back to python, returning True if %ERRORLEVEL% is 0 and False otherwise. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can do this without having to mess with python, either by setting a compiler flag or writing something in my c++ code.

Comment: @AccursedWalrus Ignoring a syntax error is like ignoring the end of the world - it simply cannot be done. What you have now seems to be alright.

Comment: Take a look at the "clang python bindings" http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/bindings/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual lines of code that are syntactically correct in the context of a C++ source file are not necessarily syntactically correct by themselves.

For example this:

```
int length, width;
```

happens to be valid either as part of a `main` function or by itself -- but it has a different meaning (by itself it defines `length` and `width` as static objects).

This:

```
}
```

is valid in context, but not by itself.

There is typically no way for a compiler to ignore syntax errors. Once a syntax error has been encountered, the compiler has no way to interpret the rest of the code.

When you're reading English text, adfasff iyufoyur; ^^$(( -- but you can usually recover and recognize valid syntax after an error. Compilers for programming languages aren't designed to perform that kind of recovery; probably the nature of C++'s syntax would make it more difficult, and there's just not enough demand to make it worth doing.

I'm not sure what your criterion for a single line of code being "correct" is.  One possibility might be to write the line of code to a file, contained in a definition of `main`:

```
int main() {
    // insert arbitrary line here
}
```

and then compile the resulting source file. I'm not sure that I can see how that would be particularly useful, but it's about the closest I can come to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "each line is self-contained"? If the syntax of a line of C++ code is valid may depend largely on the code before or after that line. A given line of code might be valid within a function, but not outside a function body. So, as long as you can't define what you mean by "self-contained" it is hard to solve your problem.

Comment: For what I'm doing, a line is considered valid if and only if it could be compiled by itself in the main function that has nothing else other than `return 0;` (see the above form for reference).

Comment: Even that depends on what stands before the main function. For example a line:
    int x = MyFunction (y);
would depend on y be defined before and MyFunction to be defined in a header file.
Perhaps you tell us what you are trying to accomplish with all that. That might make it easier to help you.

Comment: And then, of course, there is the preprocessor which can turn `int length, width;` into `int float, width;` (which is invalid in almost any context) with a simple macro `#define length float`.

Comment: Yes, very true, Peter.